# Do I Have to Finish Just Cause 2 on ALL Difficulty Settings for the PS3 Platinum Trophy?

Tags: ps3, achievements, just-cause-2

On the PS3, Just Cause 2 has 3 trophies for finishing the campaign at different difficulty levels:

```
Top Agent (Bronze): Bonus for completing the game on Normal difficulty.
Heroic Agent (Silver): Bonus for compelting the game on Experienced difficulty.
Legendary Agent (Gold): Bonus for completing the game on Hardcore difficulty.
```

Since they say, "Bonus," I was under the impression that none of them were required but harder difficulties will allow you to earn rare-er trophies. But I've finished the game on Normal difficulty and earned all of the other trophies, but I still don't have a platinum.

Do I really have to earn ALL three of these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, no, you don't have to play it through 3 times if that's what you mean.

If you had started the game on a higher level and beat it, it would have given you the trophy for the level(s) below. So, if you go back and beat it on hardcore, it will give you the trophy for experienced difficulty as well.

Platinum does require you to get every single trophy, so you'll have to at least finish the game on hardcore to pick up Heroic Agent and Legen... (wait for it) ...dary Agent.

Comment: @Sonic42 Yeah. I guess since you've already beaten it, maybe you could get through hardcore difficulty pretty quick, just focusing on the story, not having to wander around, etc.

Answer (score 0):

What Doozer Blake is saying is true, but it is not possible to complete the game fully, because there are a few boxes that can't be found, so it is impossible to get the platinum.

Comment: "Completing the game" just means finishing all of the Agency missions, not getting 100% completion.